# Why does requesting an HTML page crash my local Google App Engine server?

Tags: python, internet-explorer, google-app-engine, localhost

Why does requesting an HTML page crash my local Google App Engine server?

This only happens if it's the second or third time I do a request on Internet Explorer 9, and it is not a problem with other browsers.

This is very annoying as I have to restart my server all the time.

The error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 222, in handle_request
    ----------------------------------------
    Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 54978)
        self.process_request(request, client_address)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 241, in process_request
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 254, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
      File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3932, in __init__
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\SocketServer.py", line 521, in __init__
        self.handle()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 316, in handle
        self.handle_one_request()
      File "C:\Program Files\Python25\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 310, in handle_one_request
        method()
      File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 3942, in do_GET
        self._HandleRequest()
      File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\dev_appserver.py", line 4199, in _HandleRequest
        raise e
    error: (10053, 'Software caused connection abort')
    ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: The server shouldn't unconditionally expect every socket to have a request sent on it. This crash is likely occurring when IE closes an unneeded background connection before that connection was used. The server, expecting a request on every socket, blows up if it ever gets a connection that is closed before a request is sent.

Comment: I'm not so good in those things, so I don't know how to fix it. Anyway I would like to crash Google's servers with my IE9(just for fun lol)! I knew microsoft didn't like google so much heheh

Comment: Please include the whole stacktrace and relevant bits of the logs, not just excerpts.

Comment: i've done that... do you knwo why i get this exactly? I just found a way to don't crash my server with IE: I refresh the page, if it takes more than 2 seconds to show up something in the console I refresh again and it works perfectly, as long as I do so everytime... <3 InternetExplorer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have IE9 but that seems to be like the same problem with Google Chrome:

- https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-appengine-python/0qJlx94aZAE/discussion
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/http-archive-specification/hkdkGknbpdA

Comment: I don't find an answer for my problem there. Anyway in chrome never happened. thanks anyway

Comment: Im still having this problem and I can't find an solution for this. Is quite bad to have to restart my server when I fail to refresh the ie...

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same problems. The only thing which helps is to run devappserver with specified IP address of your computer instead of running it on localhost (which is default).

like this:
`google_appengine\dev_appserver.py --address=192.168.1.33 myapp`

Please can you confirm if it works?

Comment: I had the same problem with a python development server (werkzeug) and only with internet explorer. Specifying the ip solved it.